# What are shim JavaScript libraries and why they don't support AMD?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, shim

I am going to use RequireJS to take advantage of AMD.

In RequireJS configuration, I found a `shim` block to define shim JavaScript libraries.

Can anyone please tell me the difference between AMD JavaScript libraries and shim libraries?

Answer (score 1):

A `RequireJs` module is one that follows a very specific set of rules about code -- mostly having to do with what modules are required (modules can require other modules) and what function or methods it exports.

A `shim` is a block of code used with non-ADM libraries to provide a set of hints to RequireJS that allows one to use non-AMD libraries to be loaded.

**EDIT**

In short, AMD modules start like this:

```
define(
    module_id /*optional*/, 
    [dependencies] /*optional*/, 
    definition function /*function for instantiating the module or object*/
);
```

There are some systems that use a weird wrapper to detect if AMD is available and if so they use it, else they turn `define` into a glorified `eval` statement.

Anything else is *not* an AMD module and either needs to be loaded normally or shimmed.

Comment: Thanks jeremy but my concern is deference between AMD and Non-AMD(shim) Liberies. and i am expecting some example which can demonstrate the difference.